# How to undo a resolved merge conflict?

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

I made a Pull Request to merge my branch into master, and there were merge conflicts, so I clicked on 'resolve conflicts' button in GitHub, and there were a lot of conflicts, so I just started deleting all the marked code without paying too much attention, and then I clicked the now green button above "commit changes", and then before I merge the PR into master, I decided to pull the latest changes on my VSCode, and so I ran "git pull", and everything was messed up. Random code was being deleted from my other components, and they were not working. Not all, but some. So, how do I now undo the resolved merge conflict changes?

I tried checking out to the previous commit, but nothing changes. The code that I removed is still removed. I tried running 'git reset --hard', but again, nothing changes. I want to go back to the version before I deleted all the marked code.

How do I do that?

Comment: “Nothing changes” where?

Comment: @Guildenstern I mean the component code is still messed up. In my VSCode. I reverted to the previous commit from the terminal in my VSCode.

Comment: Weird. `git reset --hard` is the standard solution to this problem.

Comment: So I just tried git checkout (old commit), and this time it worked! Now how do I make this commit my latest one, and get rid of the new one? Do I just do git add/commit/push again?

Comment: Great! If your branch is now on that commit that you checked out (with `git reset --hard`) then you can do `git push --force-with-lease <branch>`. But note that the usual caveats about “force” apply.

Comment: I did not use `git reset --hard`, I just used git checkout "old commit ID", and now I ran `git push -f <branch-name>` and I got the message `Everything up-to-date`. How do I push this commit?

Comment: Make sure that the branch is where you expect it to be with something like `git log`. Then do the “push” command that I mentioned in my last comment. You should get output like “forced update” if it succeeds.

Comment: When I run `git log`  just see a short list of the previous commits. How do I check where the branch is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253474/discussion-between-guildenstern-and-user21616350).